# Using "in" to check whether a string occurs in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

In Javascript is it possible to check whether a string occurs in an array by using the "in" operator?

For eg:

```
    var moveAnims   = new Array("fly", "wipe", "flip", "cube");

    alert("wipe" in moveAnims);
    alert("fly " in moveAnims);
    alert("fly" in moveAnims);
    alert("Cube" in moveAnims);
```

Or is the ONLY way to do it iteratively?

```
var moveAnims   = new Array("fly", "wipe", "flip", "cube");
var targets     = new Array("wipe", "fly ", "fly", "Cube");

for (var i=0; i<moveAnims.length; i++)
{
    for (var j=0; j<targets.length; j++)
        if (targets[j] == moveAnims[i])
            alert("Found "+targets[j]);
}
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript for your answer.

Comment: You cannot use `in`. This merely checks whether the a *property* with the given name exists in the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `.indexOf()` to get the position of the object. Check whether it's `-1` to see if it's not there.

Answer (score 2):

No, because the `in` operator checks the *keys* of an object, which in an array are `0, 1, 2, ...`.

You can use `indexOf`, however:

```
if(~moveAnims.indexOf("fly")) { // ~ is a useful hack here (-1 if not found, and
    // ...                      // ~-1 === 0 and is the only falsy result of ~)
}
```

Note that `indexOf` isn't available in older browsers, but there are shims out there.

Comment: The negated result of `-1` is implementation defined though. `-1` **might not** be equal to binary `1111 1111` on all systems. OP should check so that the value is/isn't equal to `-1`, it is guaranteed to work and will ease readability if code is to be passed among several developers.

Comment: @refp: Thanks for noting, but I thought the formula is just `~x === -x - 1` as also noted [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#NOT). And `- -1 - 1 === 0`.

Comment: IIRC the ecma standard doesn't force systems implementing it to use two's-complement, even though it's not common there are other systems to represent negative numbers. OP could (and probably will) be safe using your method, but it isn't 100% guaranteed.

Comment: @refp: Thanks for clarifying; I was never aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

Try [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexOf.asp)

```
moveAnims.indexOf('string')
```